# Why my linked list is printing address instead of printing values?

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

This is the code for merging of two sorted linked list (in sorted order).

My code is printing address instead of printing the sorted list.
I am unable to understand where the problem is.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class node
{
public:
    int data;
    node *next;

    node(int d)
    {
        data = d;
        next = NULL;
    }
};

node *Merge(node *head1, node *head2)
{
    if (head1 == NULL)
    {
        return head2;
    }

    if (head2 == NULL)
    {
        return head1;
    }

    node *c = NULL;
    if (head1->data < head2->data)
    {
        c = head1;
        c->next = Merge(head1->next, head2);
    }
    else
    {
        c = head2;
        c->next = Merge(head1, head2->next);
    }
    return c;
}

void InsertAtTail(node *&head, int data)
{
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = new node(data);
        return;
    }

    node *tail = head;
    while (tail->next != NULL)
    {
        tail = tail->next;
    }
    tail->next = new node(data);
    return;
}

void display(node *head)
{
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        cout << "The Linked List is empty !!";
        return;
    }

    while (head != NULL)
    {
        cout << head->data << " -> ";
        head = head->next;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    node *head1 = NULL;
    node *head2 = NULL;
    int n1, n2, data;
    cout << "Creating 1st Linked List: " << endl;
    cout << "Enter the number of nodes you want to enter: ";
    cin >> n1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the data: ";
        cin >> data;
        InsertAtTail(head1, data);
    }

    cout << "Creating 2nd Linked List: " << endl;
    cout << "Enter the number of nodes you want to enter: ";
    cin >> n2;
    for (int i = 0; i < n2; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the data: ";
        cin >> data;
        InsertAtTail(head2, data);
    }

    display(head1);
    display(head2);

    node *NewNode = NULL;
    NewNode = Merge(head1, head2);
    cout << "The sorted list is: " << endl;
    cout << NewNode << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This is the screenshot of my output:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUv7A.png

All other functions are working properly. But after after the Merge function is called it is printing address(heaxadecimal) values instead of printing the new sorted linked list.

Comment: Because NewNode is pointer. You likely wanted display(NewNode);?

Comment: Because that's what you told it to print, at `cout << NewNode`. If you want the content, you have to do more, e.g. `cout << NewNode->data`, or provide an `operator<<` overload for `node` and do `cout << *NewNode`

Comment: Be wary of a recursive `Merge()` function, depending on the OS, you will overflow your stack before you list reaches 100,000 nodes.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you just need to replace `cout << NewNode << endl;` with: `display(NewNode);`

Comment: But may I know why **cout << NewNode << endl;** is not working?

Comment: @TanyaGupta It *is* working. It is doing exactly what you told it to do: display the address of the new node..

Answer (score 0):

The second last line of code `cout << NewNode << endl;` will print the address because NewNode is a pointer instead of this call `display(NewNode)` to print all nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I just replaced `cout << NewNode << endl;` to `cout << display(NewNode) << endl;`

And, it is working.

Code is fine.
Take care of the silly errors. All the best.